How to get a date in spark sql given a year and a week number (and without resorting to LEGACY)
I am using Databricks and it does not allow setting the date to legacy (pre version3.0) mode. So then given (year, week-in-year) how can any of the  dates within that week be returned?
All the answers that I have found do require setting LEGACY and I've tried it: Databricks runtime will not allow setting it.

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/getting-date-out-of-year-and-week/td-p/6021

Sample data and desired result would be very helpful. But I would look at using the year portion of your date + INTERVAL weeks, something along those lines.

@Andrew There is no interval weeks in spark 3.0+  https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/data-types/interval-type.html

try dateadd(WEEK, 5, '2024-01-01').  

@Andrew  Go ahead and make an answer. It may not handle edge cases like the last week of the year/ first week of the year perfectly but it's probably the best approach available
